# {MYSQL}How to get a row, using COUNT(*), to tell you how many times a number has been used

Tags: mysql

This is my code:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(shippedDate, orderDate) AS '# Days', COUNT(*) 
FROM datenumtest2 
GROUP BY '# Days' 
ORDER BY '# Days'
```

the results give me:

[image]

In the # Days, there are 3 number 5's. I would like the output in my code to be

```
Days: 5   COUNT(*): 3
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mysql you should use backtics for column name and not quote

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(shippedDate, orderDate) AS `# Days`, COUNT(*) 
FROM datenumtest2 
GROUP BY `# Days`
ORDER BY `# Days`
```

or simple days

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(shippedDate, orderDate) AS Days, COUNT(*) 
FROM datenumtest2 
GROUP BY Days
ORDER BY Days
```

Comment: @JorgeCampos   ..many thanks  ...but for double quotes   I seem to remember that functions as a  single quote .. takea look  at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks so much! Its working just like I needed it to.

Comment: Single quotes is for string literals (SQL ANSI), backticks is mysql specific while double quotes is also SQL ANSI to define delimiters (fields names, etc.). I happen to have an online link of spec of the [SQL Ansi version 99](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf) take a look at the page at the page 129 in the definition of A regular identifier (item 26)  :)

Answer (score 0):

It should work that you pass in the "# Days" alias to the count() function: `` count(`# Days`) ``should do the trick. Be careful with your alias, as a note: treat it with the same formatting principles as column names. `no_days`,`days_diff`,or just `days` should do the trick.